# std::vector<int> как параметр в функцию которая принимает std::vector<std::array<int, 3>> без копии?

Tags: c++

Есть у меня метод

```
void foo(std::vector<std::array<int, 3>> iVec){
....
}
```

Этот метод уже готов и я не хочу менять его имплементацию.

Проблема в том, что у меня как параметр уже готов вот такой вектор `std::vector<int>`

В памяти это одно и тоже, так как что такой вектор `std::vector<std::array<int, 3>>`, что такой `std::vector<int>` (в этом векторе каждая позиция умножена на 3, чтоб соответствовать), занимают одно и тоже место в памяти.

То есть теоритически я мог бы использовать `std::move` или что то такое, но проблема в том, что размер этих векторов не одинаковый...

В общем я не знаю как сделать.

Как передать мой вектор как параметр в функцию без того, чтоб делать копирование...

Надеюсь у меня получилось обьяснить, что я хочу.

Если что спрашивайте

**Правка**

Я так понимаю, что ответ @gbg правильный, только я не совсем понимаю, что значит добавить два указателя в функцию, так что если кто то понимает, добавте пожалуйста пример

Answer (score 2):

С точки зрения сиплюсплюса, это две совершенно разные, несовместимые между собой, инстантации шаблона `vector<>`.

Вашу функцию можно переделать так, чтобы она лопала два указателя на `int`. Тогда со скрипом прокатит, даже без копирования.

Comment: Можете добавить пример? А то не совсем пойму, что значит добавить два указателя...